# Minimum weight $k-$path cover on a DAG proof verification

Tags: dynamic-programming, dag, vertex-cover

Suppose you are given a directed acyclic graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and an
integer $k \leq n$. Each edge has an associated weight $w(u,v)$. We want to find $k-$vertex-disjoint paths that cover all vertices of the graph such that it minimizes the total sum of the weights of all edges in the paths. (assume such $k-$ path cover exists).

I am trying to design an $O(n^{k+3})$ dynamic program for the problem. Namely, fix a topological sort $u_1, ..., u_n$ of the DAG vertices. Let $dp(v_1, ..., v_k, i)$ denote the minimum total sum of weights of a $k-$path-cover starting at vertices $v_1, ..., v_k$, and covering vertices $u_{i}, ..., u_n$. Then we have the recurrence:

$$dp(v_1, ..., v_k, i) = \min_{j : (v_j,u_i) \in E}\{w(v_j, u_i)+dp(v_1, ..., v_{j-1}, u_i, v_{j+1}, ..., v_k, i+1)\}$$

if $\exists v_j : (v_j, u_i)\in E$ and $\infty$ if not. (I am skipping the base cases here for $i=n$ as it is trivial to handle).

The recurrence just means that path $j$ is extended from ending at $v_j$ to now end at $u_i$. The crucial thing to note is that $u_i$ does not point to any vertex from $u_1, ..., u_{i-1}$ as that would contradict the topological sort order, which ensures that the path built by the DP is vertex disjoint.

The final solution to the problem is simply $\displaystyle dp(\phi, \phi, ..., \phi, 1)$ where $\phi$ is a virtual vertex that is connected to all vertices of $G$ with cost $0$. This DP has $O((n+1)^{k}n)=O(n^{k+2})$ states, and each state takes $O(n)$ time to compute.

**Does this solution sound right**? My main concern is if the paths generated by the DP are vertex disjoint.

Comment: The way to know whether the paths are vertex disjoint is to prove that they will be.  What attempts have you made to prove this or search for a counterexample?  What progress have you made?

Comment: @D.W. I can now prove that the algorithm returns the minimum weight of paths that are vertex disjoint and concatenation of the topological sort I fixed (because each vertex is assigned to exactly one path if $dp$ is finite). I can also prove that for optimal paths $P_1^\ast, ..., P_k^\ast$, it can be generated by concatenation and inserting vertices in the order of the topological sort that I fixed. This should be sufficient to prove that the generated paths have minimum weight since the $dp$ value is precisely the total weight of the paths.

Comment: Have you answered your own question?  If so, I encourage you to answer your own in the question in the space for an answer below.